# Подскажите, как включить отображение объема данных в таблицах. DBeaver?

Tags: mysql, linux, dbeaver

DBeaver Версия 23.1.3.202307231901
Хотелось бы иметь показатель объема данных в таблицах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видел такое решение на скриншоте. Но меня тревожит фактор, что там был Windows + оч. старая версия dbeaver.
Выглядело, это так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение в виде.
Правой кнопкой мыши на бд. Сonnection view >> показывать статистику.